# Sending and receiving data sms does absolutely not work

Tags: android, sms

I want to send and receive data sms by specific port. My code is very simple and i searched many but app never enters onReceive method in the SmsReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver superclass. Where is my wrong?

Sending snippet:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
byte[] smsBody = "hello".getBytes();
short port=6393;
phone="09121111111";
smsManager.sendDataMessage(phone, null,  port, smsBody, null, null);
```

and my broadcast receiver registeration in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:port="6393"
            android:scheme="sms" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also app gives these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Furthermore i try to send and receive text message in parallel app and it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

did you granted needful permissions? like this for example:

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that app gives these permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same situation.And solution is for me I deleted '0' in front of the phone number.And solved the problem.

Comment: If you still have a problem.You can use OTP for Android.This is stabil and working succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, which works fine:

```
<receiver android:name="za.co.mtn.ti.notifier.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:host="localhost" />
                <data android:port="10001" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
```

Are you sure that you're sending the SMS correctly?